# Prove that if $u+H = v+H$ then $f(u)+H=f(v)+H$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> > Let $V$ be a vector space ( finite dimension ) and let $K_{0},...K_{n}$ be subspaces of $V$ with : $K_{0} = \left\{0 \right\} ,K_{1} , .... , K_{n-1} , K_{n}=V$ , and such that :
> >
> > $K_{0}\subseteq K_{1} \subseteq K_{2} ....\subseteq K_{n-1} \subseteq K_{n},   $
> >
> > Let $H$ be a subspace of $V$ and $f$ an endomorphism. We suppose that H is stable under f.

Our teacher says that we have the 3 following statement ( if  $u,v\in V$) :

a) And $u\equiv v$ mod $H$ then :

$$f(u)\equiv f(v)\; mod \;H$$

b) And $u+H=v+H$ then :

$$f(u)+H = f(v)+H$$

> > If we define $\pi:  V\:\longrightarrow V/H $ as the canonical projection and let
> >
> > $$g =\pi \;\circ f $$

Then :

c) 
$g = 0$ ,  if and only if , $\;f(V) \subseteq H$.

And if $f^{-1}(H) = H $ , then Ker($g$) = $H$

Any help for any statement would be a lot appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is there a flag of subspaces $K_0,\dots,K_n$ in this question that is never referred to?

Comment: What are your thoughts and the problem and what have you tried? The question is missing any effort you made to solve the problem.

Comment: Hello @Christoph , There was also some statements concerning the subspaces but I understood them, and I thought that maybe it was useful to prove the rest. 
For a) I have absolutely no clue , for c) Maybe using : Ker($g_{1}\circ g_{2}$)=$(g_{2})^{-1}$(Ker($g_{1}$))

Answer (score 1):

If $u+H = v+H$, then $u-v\in H$, and since $H$ is stable under $f$, 
$$f(u)-f(v) = f(u-v) \in H$$
but this is the same as saying that $f(u) + H = f(v) + H$.

Comment: Thanks @Azif00 , any hint for c)